# collimation of a ion beam with many charge states

Tags: matlab, simulation, montecarlo

I'm simulating an ion beam with different charge states passing through two pinholes. I'm using random angles, from an external function, to evaluate the velocity components along the axes.
In order to evaluate the particle motion I'm solving the differential equation:

```
O=[0 0 0]';
f = @(t,ys) [ys(4:6); O];
options=odeset('RelTol',1e-7,'Events',@(t,ys)Event_Stop_Sorgente(t,ys,Pinhole1));
[t,ys] = ode23t(f,tspan,y_sorgente(i,:),options);
```

and it works fine as long as the beam has no angular spread and the initial condition vector is `y_sorgente = [0 0 0 0 0 v_z]`. I suppose it works fine with angular spread as well because the trajectories are straight lines, as they are supposed to be.
The external function get some points from a sferic surface and uses their coordinates as direction cosine to get the velocity components from its modulus.

The problem I have is that only few particle with charge state 1+ can pass the pinhole, all the others can not and it doesn't make any sense. I have the same issue even if each particle has the same modulus of velocity. I'm doing something wrong, but I can't understand what, any suggestion?
I can provide the full code if you want to check it.

Comment: Sounds like you need help from a physicist, not a programmer.